# Увеличение высоты тега li в меню

Tags: html, css

Есть

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #ff4800;
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}

.spisok {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.items {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
}

.spisok ul {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
}

.items li {
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.items li:hover {
  background-color: #d23a00;
  transition: .5s;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <p><a href="index.html">Broad Smile</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="spisok">
    <ul class="items">
      <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Покупка доната</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Серверы</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Правила</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Личный кабинет</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при наведении вкладка немного темнела. Это выделение должно быть 100% высоты меню. Здесь рабочий код, но когда я хочу указать line-height в процентах у тега li (в селекторе .items li{}), ничего не происходит. Но если указываю в пикселях - все получается. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: `я хочу указать line-height в процентах` так `line-height` это не высота... Это межстрочный интервал. http://htmlbook.ru/css/line-height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при наведении вкладка немного темнела. Это выделение должно быть 100% высоты меню.

Я кое что из твоих стилей закомментировал - т.к. это вообще ни на что в примере не влияло...

Что добавил - я так же пометил.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #ff4800;
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}

.spisok {
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  /*
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  */
}

.items {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  /*
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  */
}

.spisok ul {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
}

.items li {
  padding: 0 20px;
  /* Вот эту часть добавил */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.items li:hover {
  background-color: #d23a00;
  transition: .5s;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <p><a href="index.html">Broad Smile</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="spisok">
    <ul class="items">
      <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Покупка доната</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Серверы</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Правила</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Личный кабинет</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```